# Drive letter of given file in windows batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm writing a script where I will get a file name as a parameter. The file will be absolute. (Ideally the solution would support relative files as well, but I can live with absolute-only). It is unknown if the file already exist.

I want to get the Drive letter of the file.

Example:

```
myScript.bat C:\exampleFolder\somefile.txt D:\someOtherFolder\differentfile.txt
```

myScript.bat:

```
echo First argument: %1
echo Second argument: %2
REM Its the next line I have trouble with.
echo Drive letter of second argument: %MAGIC%2
```

expected output:

```
First argument: C:\exampleFolder\somefile.txt
Second argument: D:\someOtherFolder\differentfile.txt
Drive letter of second argument: D:
```

Context: I want to write a script that does some file copy. But the file may appear at the target destination only at once. As soon as its created it must already be complete. So I want to write a script that copies the file to `TARGET_DRIVE\tmp` and then move it to the destination.

I thought about passing the Drive letter as a third argument. But that seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I want to get the Drive letter of the file in the 2nd argument

Use `%~d2`.

**myScript.bat:**

```
@echo off
echo First argument: %1
echo Second argument: %2
echo Drive letter of second argument: %~d2
```

Example Output:

```
F:\test>myScript C:\exampleFolder\somefile.txt D:\someOtherFolder\differentfile.txt
First argument: C:\exampleFolder\somefile.txt
Second argument: D:\someOtherFolder\differentfile.txt
Drive letter of second argument: D:

F:\test>
```

---

#### Parameter Extensions

> When an argument is used to supply a filename then the following
>   extended syntax can be applied:
>
> we are using the variable %1 (but this works for any parameter)
>
> %~f1 Expand %1 to a Fully qualified path name - C:\utils\MyFile.txt
>
> %~d1 Expand %1 to a Drive letter only - C:
>
> %~p1 Expand %1 to a Path only e.g. \utils\ this includes a trailing \ which will be interpreted as an escape character by some commands.
>
> %~n1 Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension C:\utils\MyFile or if only a path is present (with no trailing backslash) - the last folder in that path.
>
> %~x1 Expand %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt
>
> %~s1 Change the meaning of f, n, s and x to reference the Short 8.3 name (if it exists.)
>
> %~1   Expand %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
>
> %~a1 Display the file attributes of %1
>
> %~t1 Display the date/time of %1
>
> %~z1 Display the file size of %1
>
> %~$PATH:1 Search the PATH environment variable and expand %1 to the fully qualified name of the first match found.
>
> The modifiers above can be combined:
>
> %~dp1 Expand %1 to a drive letter and path only
>
> %~sp1 Expand %1 to a path shortened to 8.3 characters
>
> %~nx2 Expand %2 to a file name and extension only

Source [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Comment: How do I strip the colon off?

Comment: @K._ Add the following two lines: `set _l=%~d2` followed by `echo %_l:~0,1%`