# How to get the PID of the windows cmd I'm in

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I want to create a unique directory for the time a process runs (to complete the copy process I described in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1050168/116338)). I've tried `%random%` but it changes too slowly. Waiting is not a viable option, because I write this to speed my copy process up.

So, I'm looking for the PID of the current process of the script I'm in to name the path like it. I need to get it into a variable.

Its fine that the PID gets reused by another process later on, it just needs to be unique as long as my script runs, as I will delete the directory in the end anyway.

I don't need the PID of another process, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618914/getting-process-id-of-exe-running-in-bat-file) didn't help me.

I considered using the combination of source and target path (sans the `\`), but that could collide with other copy actions running at the same time (e.G. one copies all txt files, another all jpg files both from and to the same directories).

My script is called from another script, so I could present each copy with a distinctive argument, but I'd rather not, cause then I would need to do that in other situations where I want to use the copy too.

Comment: ServerFault dupe: [how to get own process pid from the command prompt in windows](http://serverfault.com/a/654029)

Comment: @DavidPostill Holy ****. There is no easier way for that?

Comment: If there was dbenham would have posted it. He is one of the cmd line experts around here.

Comment: Ah, well. Thank you then. Should I delete the question here then?

Comment: I would leave it open. Then people searching here will find the link. If I have time later I might write an answer referring the to SF one.

Comment: Could you run from Powershell? There is a `$pid` variable that, "`Contains the process identifier (PID) of the process that is hosting the current Windows PowerShell session.`" https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx If this is slowing down your project, you may want to consider alternative approaches to having a (temporarily) unique number.

Comment: @root I have to check PowerShell, I think its available but I have no experience with it. Currently I give in the unique identifier from the calling script (which works for the moment, but is unstable and bound to fail). I'm all ears to how a temporarily unique number could be created.

Comment: Also keep in mind there may be no easier bulletproof generic way for doing it, but for a given situation you might be able to make some assumptions that might not be universally true but good enough for your case. For example if you can guarantee that your batch file is never started twice at the same time you can just filter the commandline for your batchs path,..

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I'm losing sight of your particular goals with this task, it would be hard to suggest appropriate alternatives. Why do you mention that `%random%` updates too slowly? If you don't want to run your script with Powershell, you could call `$pid` through cmd using command: `powershell $pid`, but I suspect this will also be too slow. I believe doing this will also launch a temporary process to access Powershell, giving a different PID as a result each time it is called in this way.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT MY CODE!**

```
set T=%TEMP%\sthUnique.tmp
wmic process where (Name="WMIC.exe" AND CommandLine LIKE "%%%TIME%%%") get ParentProcessId /value | find "ParentProcessId" >%T%
set /P A=<%T%
set PID=%A:~16%
```

The PID of the current process is stored in the `PID` variable.

I don't remember who made this, but it works. There is probably some unnecessary code, but I can't deconstruct it.

Comment: I really don't know what to do with this answer (especially after I don't have the situation anymore). I want to downvote it because you don't understand it (and it thous could be dangerous), but its beautiful in its brevity that wants me to upvote it. I would be very grateful if you could deconstruct it and find out how it works, then explain it. If this works and is well explained (especially its border conditions on when it will not work etc.) it would be a true marvel.

Comment: It works well, the only issue is I don't understand it. All you do is place it at the top of the script, then you can access the PID of the current window in the `PID` variable.

Comment: What a great opportunity to learn something. You write your language of choice is batch and here you have a marvel. Something to gain insight from. I on the other hand could not care less about batch; I use it because I must, not because I want. I leave it up to you. Currently I will absent from voting on this, one way or the other, but this is the kind of answer that can get a LOT of upvotes over the time (if improved). And if I found such a marvel in my code and don't understand it, I would start picking it apart until I did. So, choose wisely, Ender Scythe.

Answer (score 0):

I parsed the above answer and got it into a one liner, though it's a bit long for a one-liner.

Here is both the interactive and batch file forms:

#### interactive:

```
for /f "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=="  %A in (`wmic process where ^(Name^="WMIC.exe" AND CommandLine LIKE "%%%%TIME%%%%"^) get ParentProcessId /value`) do set "PID=%A"
```

#### in a batchfile

```
for /f "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=="  %%A in (`wmic process where ^(Name^="WMIC.exe" AND CommandLine LIKE "%%%%TIME%%%%"^) get ParentProcessId /value`) do set "PID=%%A"
```

#### Here is the parsing of the above answer:

```
set T=%TEMP%\sthUnique.tmp # used by the next command
```

Sets an arbitrary temporary file & path

```
wmic process where (Name="WMIC.exe" AND CommandLine LIKE "%%%TIME%%%") get ParentProcessId /value | find "ParentProcessId" >%T%
```

This is the most novel line; it tells WMIC to look up it's own process based on the fact it was ran right now and report back it's parent PID ( which is CMD) Pretty recursive! Then it writes this info to the temp file.

```
set /P A=<%T%
```

This sets the variable A by reading the temp file above.

```
set PID=%A:~16%
```

This parses out the ProcessID= stuff using a substring.